# Gateway Server Jump Bastion Host Local Setup

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I want to ssh to a remote private host using an intermediate (bastion, jump, gateway) server. This command works fine:

```
ssh gateway ssh private
```

With this ~/.ssh/config setup:

```
Host gateway
  User gateway-user
  HostName XX.XX.XX.XX
  RequestTTY force
```

How can I implement this in my ~/.ssh/config? I've tried numerous iterations of ProxyCommand with no luck. I want to use the identity file located on gateway host to access private hosts. I want to be able to do:

```
ssh private
```

I am aware of the technique described here, but it requires my public key to be on all the private hosts, but I don't want that:

http://www.lorrin.org/blog/2014/01/10/one-liner-ssh-via-jump-box-using-proxycommand/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, configure your ssh keys on the gateway so you can ssh to private. Then on your client, create a separate private/public key pair that you use to authenticate on the gateway. E.g. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_gateway`.

Then on the gateway, use the `command=` syntax in your authorized_keys file. For example, your entry might look like this:

```
command="sh -c 'ssh private ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:-}'" ssh-rsa AAAAB3....
```

Search the sshd manpage for `command="command"` for more info. Be sure to add the id_gateway.pub key to this line. Then in your `.ssh/config` on your client, add an entry like this:

```
Host private
User gateway-user
Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
IdentitiesOnly Yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_gateway
```

Now, from your client you should be able to `ssh private` and get directly in. This even works for `scp` and `sftp`.

**Extra Credit**

If you want to use this for multiple servers, but only want to manage one public key on the gateway, you can use the following trick. `sshd` by default only allows certain variables to be received from the local environment. One of these is `LC_PAPER` which is rarely used for anything. So we can use it to pass the server's hostname as follows:

First, change the public key entry to

```
command="sh -c 'ssh $LC_PAPER ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:-}'" ssh-rsa AAAAB3...
```

Then on your client, add a function to your `.bashrc` file (or whatever shell you use) that looks like this:

```
ssh_proxy() {
  LC_PAPER=$1 /usr/bin/ssh $*
}
```

Then make an alias to if you want:

```
alias ssh=ssh_proxy
```

Finally, add `Host` sections to your `.ssh/config` like the one shown above. for example:

```
Host private2
User gateway-user
Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
IdentitiesOnly Yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_gateway
```

Now you should be able to do `ssh private` and `ssh private2` with just the one public key on the gateway.

Comment: This is along the right lines. How can I SSH to multiple private hosts and only have 1 public key stored on gateway? Is there a way to pass in the requested hostname?

Comment: I updated my answer to address that.

Comment: Is there a way to keep this contained in the .ssh/config file. Also, it would be ideal if the hosts could share a single entry.

Comment: Nope. You can't put env variables in the `.ssh/config`. You could just manually run `LC_PAPER=private ssh private`. If you use a `Host *` block at the end of `.ssh/config` you would only need 1 entry. BTW, why can't you just have multiple private/public keys? It would be much easier.

Comment: I got scp to work like this: scp_proxy() {
 LC_PAPER=`echo "$1" | cut -f1 -d":"` /usr/bin/scp $*
}
alias scp=scp_proxy