# SSHing into VPS with single IP

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, router, virtualbox

I have Comcast Internet for my home, and have a single IP.

I've set my hardware router to direct SSH to a physical Linux server.

On my physical Linux server, I've created a virtual private server using Virtual Box and it also runs Linux.

How can I remotely SSH into the VPS?

Comment: Maybe use another port than 22 to point to the VPS?

Comment: What networking mode is the VM using?  If NAT, consider using bridged. That way the VM gets its own IP address and you can change the port-forwarding rule to point at the VM address.

Comment: @Paul.  Note really sure.  Will NAT be configured in the guest?  Would doing so be the "normal" way to set it up?  Thanks

Comment: It would be defined in the guest VM settings in VirtualBox.  The default way is NAT I believe, but the "normal" way is dependent on the application.

Comment: This is very similar to this [question][1].


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/922713/gateway-server-jump-bastion-host-local-setup/922733#922733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Use your router to forward another port (eg, 2222) to port 22 on the VM. Login to your VM using this port instead of 22.
2. Use double hop ssh to login to your Linux server and then into the VM:

   `ssh -A -t your.hostname ssh -A -t your.VM`

Of course, this assumes that the VM is using bridged networking on your home LAN - if it's using NAT then thing get a lot more complicated (I'd recommend you configure the VM to use bridged network before you experiment with allowing ssh access).